# Wrap live webapp in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

Hi I'm trying to wrap a live webapp into Phonegap.

I tried two methods:

1) use javascript: window.location = "http://www.google.com"

this ended up in opening the android browser directing to the url.

2) in main activity for Phonegap4android, use super.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

this ended up in a network connection error. But the url is apparently available form the browser.

Any comment and help is greatly appreciated.

## EDIT

I've added permission  into the AndroidManifest.xml already. Thanks to @Nezam

Comment: add the proper PERMISSIONS

Comment: Thx. I added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> into the AndroidManifest.xml already. Is it enough?

Comment: yes that coupled with loadUrl method

Comment: And the error is still there after adding the permission